# Which version of Apache Tomcat is suited for development?

Tags: java, tomcat

Which version of Apache Tomcat is suited for development? When I get to Apache Tomcat download page, there's not a lot information on that issue.

Thanks for hgelping

Comment: which are the frameworks you are going to work for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by *issue*? The latest version of Apache Tomcat (v7.0) seems a good choice for your development, at least if you are using Java 1.6. If you are using Java 1.5, go for Tomcat v6. If you are using an older version of Java, you may consider using Tomcat 5.5.

This [which version? page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) could be usefull for you in order to select the adequate version of Tomcat, regarding the JSP and Java version you are using...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "Topic" instead of "Issue".

Comment: The only problem with Tomcat 7.0 is that it is still in beta, so you should be a bit cautious about using it in *production* ...